# Laravel 4 - Artadarek/OAuth-4-laravel installation issue

Tags: laravel, installation, package

i have tried installing the oauth-4-laravel package on my app but seems it is not installing, when i checked app/config/packages i did not find any artdarek folder, what am i doing wrong?

STEPS I HAVE TAKEN

1. "require": {
   "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master"
   }
2. composer update

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading the installation instructions for that package...

You have only done the first two steps.  You need to do the following as well:

- Registering the Package
- Configuration

Comment: this is the error it gave http://laravel.io/bin/42lb9, then the artdarek/oauth-4-laravel in the vendor folder it is not there.

Comment: What does your composer.json file look like?